# Why won't my wireless interface pass traffic to my network?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wifi

I am trying to setup a wifi access point with my Ubuntu server. I am having some trouble getting everything working correctly. Mainly the problem appears to be with routing or iptables but I cannot say for certain.

My network is setup like so;

Server is NS01 (Ubuntu 11.10 server amd64)

Interfaces: eth0 (primary), br0 (bridges eth1 and wlan0) and , tun0 (OpenVPN).

What does work: When I bring the access point online the bridge comes up and my laptop can phone get an IP address lease from my DHCP server.

What does not work: When I try to ping the new host (my phone or laptop) from my workstation I get a reply back of `Destination host unreachable icmp_seq=1`. I have checked iptables and I pretty sure that is working fine, I have INPUT and OUTPUT set to ACCEPT so iptables is pretty permissive.

I am thinking it is a routing issue but the routing table looks "ok" to me.

Can anyone give me some insight to what I may need to look at, I am so close to getting this thing working.

Comment: What are the addresses and masks on the interfaces and hosts?

Comment: The addresses are `eth0 = 10.0.0.15/24` and `br0 = 10.0.0.16/24` my android phone got a lease of `10.0.0.138/24` I want the wireless to be an extension of my LAN not a seperate network.

Comment: I suspect then the problem is that you have an address on eth0 but it should be in the bridge if it is possible to add another interface.

Comment: I can't do that, eth0 is for my DNS, LDAP, DHCP and OpenVPN service(s). Unless adding eth0 to the bridge will not interupt traffic because I was aware it would which is why I am using eth1 instead.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I am not 100% sure, but I am fairly certain that you need to put your bridge/eth1 interface and your eth0 interface into separate subnets otherwise you are trying to route within the same subnet and I can't see how that could work.

Comment: That was one possibility I had thought of too, if I did that then is there a way to make my DHCP server listen on both subnets and hand out leases accordingly? That is really the only thing stopping my from doing that in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1824/discussion-between-blankabout-and-solignis)

Comment: Hmm, clicked on the make chat link & was logged out, so I'll give that a miss. I guess Linux hosts act like normal routers so you will have to tell it to 'forward broadcasts' or whatever the iptables equivalent is, on the interface that does not have the DHCP server on it, so that IP address requests etc. get forwarded to the other network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your network is flat you shouldn't need iptables (you may, but I don't think so).  The first thing to ensure is that your kernel will forward ipv4 packets by checking on the following kernel parameter:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You will either get a 1 or a 0, 1 being forwarding enabled.  If you get a 0 try running the command:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

And trying to ping from your client again.  If it still does not work I would open two terminals on the Ubuntu bridge machine and run tcpdump listening for icmp on each interface:

*terminal 1*

```
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
```

*terminal 2*

```
tcpdump -i br0 icmp
```

And then try pinging from your workstation inside interface (`eth0 10.0.0.15`) and see if you see packets hit both interfaces.  You may need to do some tweaking with `brctl` but you shouldn't need to have any specific routes since the network is flat.  I would also check to make sure that your wifi card is in the correct mode, probably infrastructure or possibly ad-hoc with `iwconfig`.  As strange as it may seem this may be easier to do with different networks and some iptables/routing foo, at least it will make it easier to identify where the traffic is being dropped.

Comment: Traffic is not showing up when I run `tcpdump -i br0 icmp` its like that data is not making even to the bridge. On the other hand my gateway is constantly in chat with my eth0 interface but I think that is unrelated.

Comment: If you run `tcpdump -i br0` do you see any traffic at all?  I think you should at least see arp whois packets traversing that interface when you ping.

Comment: yeah I see a huge amount of ARP requests, all of them are coming from my workstation VMADMIN. All of the request though are for my 10.0.0.0/24 subnet not the 10.0.1.0/24 which is my wireless.

Comment: I just want to make sure I have this clear: `eth0` is on `10.0.0.0/24`, `eth1` is on `10.0.0.0/24`, `br0` is on `10.0.0.0/24`, `wlan0` is on `10.0.1.0/24` and your "client (android/laptop)" is getting a `10.0.1.0/24` address?  Is my understanding of your network correct?

Comment: No, `eth0 = 10.0.0.0/24`, `eth1 = bridge slave`, `wlan0 = bridge slave`, `br0 = 10.0.1.0/24`. My Android/Laptop are getting leases for `10.0.1.0/24`

Comment: ahh, try adding a route for 10.0.1.0/24 to your workstation with `ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 dev br0`.  In an earlier comment you stated that `br0` is at `10.0.0.16/24` btw.

Comment: yeah my original goal was to keep everything under 1 subnet, but did not see that happening so I just popped out another subnet. Is my original idea still possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1825/discussion-between-d34dh0r53-and-solignis)

Comment: As per discussion in chat, the problem is no solvable with my current equipment. I need a different Wifi NIC, Still after helping me for several hours I giving the answer points to d34dh0r53.